# How is sound produced in pea whistles? (I think they're called police whistles in the US.)

Tags: fluid-dynamics, acoustics, resonance

I read the topic called 'Whistle Physics' on this forum. From what I gathered there, @alephzero seemed to be saying that changes in air pressure cause air to be alternately sucked in and pushed out of the whistle's slit, which sets up sound waves – and it's this that causes the noise, rather than the vortices. Have I understood this correctly? Would this be an effective explanation in its simplest form?...

[image: Sketch of how a whistle works]

<1> The referee blows air into the opening of the whistle.
<2> The air flows across a slot at the top of the whistle, which deflects some of the air out of the whistle and some into the inner chamber.
<3> The stream of air that is deflected upwards curls around to form a spinning vortex. 
<4> The rest of the air flows around the inside of the curved chamber, creating more vortices. 
<5> The difference in pressure between the air flowing across the slot and the air inside the whistle alternately sucks air in and out of the chamber, creating sound waves.
<6> The whistle has a natural frequency of vibration, which depends on its size and shape. Different whistles produce higher or lower notes.
<7> Many whistles have a ball inside them, called a pea, which is often made from cork. The pea bounces around inside the chamber, changing the pitch of the sound waves and creating a warbling sound.
<8> Sound waves leave the whistle through the slot at the top, creating the piercing noise that we hear when the referee blows the whistle.